# Android Unit Test: How do I test if retryWhen from RxJava is called certain numbers?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, rx-java

## What I have

I have a static class `APIHelper` and there's a single public function

```
/**
 * Calls APIs that return Observable<Response<*>>.
 * @param observable an Observable<Response<SomeModel>> you can get from NetworkServiceGenerator.getApi()
 * @param maxRetryCount retry count to try up to. Default is 3 (see DEFAULT_RETRY_COUNT)
 * @param customErrorToCatch if included, you can throw any Exception with custom logic
 * @param haltIfThrownType if included, you can halt the operation even before try count didn't reach retry count
 */
fun <T : Response<*>> call(
        observable: Observable<T>,
        maxRetryCount: Int = DEFAULT_MAX_RETRY_COUNT,
        retryIntervalInSec: Long = DEFAULT_RETRY_INTERVAL_SEC,
        customErrorToCatch: ((response: T) -> Unit)? = null,
        haltIfThrownType: ((throwable: Throwable?) -> Boolean)? = null): Observable<T> {
    return observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                    if (customErrorToCatch != null) {
                        customErrorToCatch(it)
                    }
                    throwNetworkException(it)
                }
            }
            .retryWhen { errors ->
                errors.zipWith(
                        Observable.range(1, maxRetryCount),
                        BiFunction { throwable: Throwable, count: Int -> Pair(throwable, count) })
                        .flatMap { pair: Pair<Throwable, Int> ->
                            val throwable = pair.first
                            val currentCount = pair.second
                            val isNetworkException = pair.first is NetworkException
                            if (shouldStopRetrying(haltIfThrownType, throwable, currentCount, maxRetryCount)) {
                                Observable.error(throwable)
                            } else {
                                Observable.timer(retryIntervalInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            }
                        }
            }
}
```

I was able to verify success case and failed case by doing this

```
@Test
fun testSuccessful() {
    val response = ResponseModel("success", "0", "")
    Mockito.`when`(api.requestLogout()).thenReturn(Observable.just(Response.success(response)))
    val result = APIHelper.call(api.requestLogout())
    val testObserver = TestObserver<Response<ResponseModel>>()
    result.subscribe(testObserver)
    testObserver.assertComplete()
    testObserver.assertNoErrors()
    testObserver.assertValueCount(1)
    val isSuccessful = testObserver.values()[0].isSuccessful
    assert(isSuccessful)
}

@Test
fun testError() {
    val response = Response.error<ResponseModel>(
            400,
            ResponseBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                    "{\"result\":\"fail\",\"errorCode\":\"0\",\"errorMessage\":\"some error\"}")
    )
    Mockito.`when`(api.requestLogout()).thenReturn(Observable.just(response))
    val result = APIHelper.call(api.requestLogout())
    val testObserver = TestObserver<Response<ResponseModel>>()
    result.subscribe(testObserver)
    testObserver.assertNotComplete()
    testObserver.assertError(NetworkException(400, ""))
    testObserver.assertValueCount(0)
}
```

## Setup

- Kotlin
- Mockito 3.x.x
- mockk 1.9.x

## Question

I want to test two things

1. `retryWhen` was entered `maxRetryCount` times and failed.
2. try `n` numbers and pass mock response at n+1 attempt to test success case.

## What I tried

I tried to make a function inside `retryWhen` block (see `shouldStopRetrying(...)`), but I don't really know how to count that specific function invocation from a static class.

Thank you in advance!

## EDIT

So I edited the function to be an extension function of `Observable`

```
fun <T: Response<*>> Observable<T>.call(
        subscribeOn: Scheduler = Schedulers.io(),
        observeOn: Scheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(),
        maxRetryCount: Int = DEFAULT_MAX_RETRY_COUNT,
        retryIntervalInSec: Long = DEFAULT_RETRY_INTERVAL_SEC,
        customErrorToCatch: ((response: T) -> Unit)? = null,
        haltIfThrownType: ((throwable: Throwable?) -> Boolean)? = null): Observable<T> {
    return this.subscribeOn(subscribeOn)
            .observeOn(observeOn)
            .doOnNext {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                    if (customErrorToCatch != null) {
                        customErrorToCatch(it)
                    }
                    throwNetworkException(it)
                }
            }
            .retryWhen { errors ->
                errors.zipWith(
                        Observable.range(1, maxRetryCount),
                        BiFunction { throwable: Throwable, count: Int -> Pair(throwable, count) })
                        .flatMap { pair: Pair<Throwable, Int> ->
                            val throwable = pair.first
                            val currentCount = pair.second
                            if (shouldStopRetrying(haltIfThrownType, throwable, currentCount, maxRetryCount)) {
                                Observable.error(throwable)
                            } else {
                                Observable.timer(retryIntervalInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            }
                        }
            }
}
```

and my test is

```
@Test
fun testRetriableError() {
    val response = Response.error<ResponseModel>(
            500,
            ResponseBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                    "{\"result\":\"fail\",\"errorCode\":\"4\",\"errorMessage\":\"\"}")
    )
    Mockito.`when`(api.requestLogout()).thenReturn(Observable.just(response))
    val testScheduler = TestScheduler(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    val result = api.requestLogout().call(
            observeOn =  testScheduler
    )
    val testObserver = TestObserver<Response<ResponseModel>>()
    result.subscribe(testObserver)
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    testObserver.assertNotTerminated()
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    testObserver.assertNotTerminated()
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    testObserver.assertNotTerminated()
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    testObserver.assertTerminated() // <--- fails
    testObserver.assertNotComplete()
    testObserver.assertError(NetworkException(500, "Internal Server Error"))
    testObserver.assertValueCount(0)
}
```

This fails at `testObserver.assertTerminated()` with the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Subscriber still running! (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0)
```

However, when I debug this test and run them line by line (taking enough time), the test passes.

I almost feel like `testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` is doing nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. use a extention function, instead of passing in the observable. 2. pass in the scheduler for subscribeOn/ observeOn and timer with default parameters. You can then pass in a TestScheduler and advance the time in order to test what happens after X retries. If you have still problems, feel free to reach out.

Comment: Will try now and get back to you. Thank you for helping out @HansWurst!

Comment: @HansWurst I edited the question to add what I have tried after your comment. I feel like I'm almost there.

Comment: You have to pass in a scheduler into `Observable.timer(retryIntervalInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`. It otherwise uses a default scheduler. There is a overload, where you can pass in a scheduler, like `#timer(time, unit, scheduler)`. You could just use the `Schedulers.single()` for time jobs, but remember to pass it in as default param in order to advanceTime on the Testscheduler, otherwise you have concurrency issues in order to sync the test junit thread with passed in scheduler.